# How to pass an error message if a user tries to bypass the login process in PHP?

Tags: php, authentication

I am currently learning php and I was trying to work out how to display an error message if a user tries to bypass username and password validation. I know there are similar questions and solutions regarding about this but I am not sure how to implement those solutions to my code.

The sequence of my code is as follows:

*A.php - User logs in and validation happens here i.e. if the username and password has a match from the database, start session and redirect and give access to B.php.*

*B.php - Can only be accessed by authorised users. If not logged in, redirect to C.php. I have the following code for B.php.*

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION["who"]) {   //checks if user is logged in
  header("location: C.php");
} else {
//other code goes here
}
?>
```

*C.php - This page destroys the session and redirects back to login page, in this case, A.php. I have the following code for C.php.*

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("location: A.php");
?>
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how do I show an error message to the user if they directly accesses B.php without going through the process of A.php. I hope that you would be able to help me with this, thank you.

Comment: Neither should be in the public scope. You should only front your `index.php` then use routing.

Comment: Why not use the session for this? Also, are you facing any **specfic** problem about this?

Comment: Just replace `header("location: C.php");` with whatever error message you want to show, and a link back to the login page. There's no need for multiple redirects.

Comment: @Jaquarh I think that "should" is a bit strong. Having a front controller / router setup is certainly a powerful technique, but there's nothing *wrong* with using the file system as your router, with a file for each entry point.

Comment: @NicoHaase tried using $_SESSION on C.php just after the session_destroy() and I tried to pass it on A.php but I does not display the error message when I directly access B.php. It just redirects back to A.php without the error message.

Comment: You're right @IMSoP, I am just a sucker for best practice.

Comment: @IMSoP I have to redirect it to A.php and show the message there.

Comment: What's the point in calling session_destroy();? And entire C.php for that matter?

Comment: "I have to" is a bit strong. **The standard** requires you to return the 403 status, not 302

Comment: @YourCommonSense A.php is the login page. Upon successful login, a session is started where it stores info of the logged in user. B.php is only accessible if the logged in user is in the database. C.php is the log out where the session is destroyed. and user is redirected to log in page

Comment: WHY would you logout a user **who didn't even logged in**?

Comment: @YourCommonSense

This is the specification

"If a user tries to access B.php page and they are not logged in, they must be
automatically redirected to the C.php page (which redirects to the login page) and then display an appropriate error message on the login page indicating that the error has occurred."

Comment: That's quite a stupid specification. In this case you have to ask someone who wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down what your code needs to do, without making any assumptions about *how* to do it:

- Show a login form
- Process the login form
- On successful login, record that the user is logged in some "permanent" way
- Check whether the user is logged in

  - If they are logged in, allow them access to some privileged content / functionality
  - If they are *not* logged in, show the login form, with a helpful message

Commonly, these would just be *functions* within the application, so you would write something like this:

```
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo "<p>You must log in to view this page</p>";
    display_login_form();
    exit;
}
```

You might want to incorporate the message into the layout of the login form, so would pass it in as a parameter:

```
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    display_login_form("You must log in to view this page");
    exit;
}
```

In your code, you've put most of those functions into their own files, so instead of just calling functions, you have to redirect the user's browser repeatedly.

That means we have to replace the parameter we passed to `display_login_form` with some other way of getting the data there. A simple way would be a query string parameter:

```
header('Location: A.php?message=You%20must%20log%20in%20to%20view%20this%20page');
exit; // important that no code runs after we've set up the redirect!
```

Having the actual text in the query string is a bit awkward, because users can edit it, and trick each other into going to URLs with weird messages on them, *it may even be a security risk*. Having a code for each possible message would be better:

```
header('Location: A.php?messagecode=page_requires_login');
exit; // important that no code runs after we've set up the redirect!
```

The additional problem you have with this is that (for reasons I'm not entirely clear on), you're redirecting *twice*, first to a page C.php, which does basically nothing, and from *there* to A.php. You'd need to pass the message along:

```
header('Location: A.php?messagecode=' . $_GET['messagecode']);
exit;
```

But again, this gets into problems of what the user can do if they mess around with the URLs...

Another option is to store the message in the session - at the moment, C.php destroys the session, but there's no reason you can't have an active session for someone who's not logged in. So you could write this:

```
$_SESSION['login_form_message'] = 'You must log in to view this page';
```

And then somewhere in A.php, this:

```
if ( isset($_SESSION['login_form_message']) ) {
    echo '<p>', $_SESSION['login_form_message'], '</p>';
    // Don't show the message again next time the page loads
    unset($_SESSION['login_form_message']);
}
```

This will keep the message "prepared" however many times you redirect, and doesn't give the user any chance to mess around with it (other than clearing their cookies, and therefore their session).

Comment: Thanks for this thorough breakdown and explanation. Will try to implement something like this on my code. Thanks again!

Comment: I have implemented this idea and I now have my C.php set where i have the session_destroy inside if($_SESSION["who"]) and i have the $_SESSION['errorMessage'] inside else.

From what I understand with my new code in C.php is that `session_destroy()` only happens only if there is a user logged in. Else the `$_SESSION[errorMessage]` then redirect to A.php. On A.php, it should show the `$_SESSION[errorMessage]`

Is this right?